# Are there examples of animals that adapt to their environment very quickly? The phenomenon is called Phenoptic Plasticity

Tags: evolution, environment

Evolution and speciation may take millions of years. This made me wonder if there is an animal that adapts itself relatively rapidly to its environment? I don't mean a simple adaptation like a change of a color by chameleons, but a real evolutionary change.

I've heard that some animals can adapt quickly to the environment like snakes (I am not sure they do). When they have a lot of water (e.g., a big river), they grow big, while the same species does not grow as big in a smaller water tank (small body of water). And when you take this animal to a bigger water it starts to grow quickly.  I want to be sure it is a snake or there is some other animals that evolve change like this...

Comment: What do you mean? All of them do. Every single one.

Comment: I've heard that some animals can adapt quickly to the environment like snakes (I am not sure). When they have a lot of water (big river ie) they grow big and the same species do not grow as big in smaller water tank (small body of water). And when you take this animal to a bigger water it stars to grow.  I want to be sure it is a snake or there is some other animals that evolve change like this...

Comment: First of all, that also happens with all animals. If you have enough food, you grow big, if you don't you remain small. Please [edit] your question and clarify.

Comment: Given your snake example, I think it is unclear whether you are interested in evolutionary change or phenotypic plasticity.

Comment: If phenoptic plasticity means changing the size due to better environment and opposite: not growing or changing (evolving) due to bad ones - I am interested in that. Thanks

Comment: @Arcadio [Phenotypic plasticity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phenotypic_plasticity) is dealing with phenotypic differences in between individuals in different environments that are not the result of differences in genotype (so that the same genotype can result in completely different phenotypes). The body size differences that you describe are often the result of this. Phenot plasticity does not involve evolution, since the genotype doesn't change. However, also the plastic response (the [reaction norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reaction_norm)) can be the target of selection and evolve.

Comment: @Arcadio You're welcome! You can edit your question to narrow down the answer set (focus on either rapid evolution or plastic responses), so that it is more well-defined and can be reopened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The snake example you provide is a single animal that adapts itself to its surroundings. **Adaptation** is similar, yet very different from **evolution**. Adaptation happens on a short timescale (as little as seconds, to perhaps years, but within a single life time, without substantial changes in DNA other than, perhaps, epigenetic ones), while evolution may occur over the course of millions of years or more, and likely involving gross changes in appearance and hereditary material. I am not entirely sure what you are exactly after.

A striking example of adaptation is the fish *[Tilapia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tilapia)*, an invasive species of fish (Fig. 1) that is capable of sustaining fresh water as well as sea water environments. The transition from one medium to the other is mediated by gross changes in endocrinology. Your specific snake example on size adaptation seems, however, unsupported based on [non-scientific websites](http://www.reptilerescue.com/petcare.shtml) at least.

[image: Nile Tilapia]
<sup>Fig. 1. Nile Tilapia. Source: [Sea EX](http://www.sea-ex.com/thailand/angling/nile-tilapia.htm)</sup>

If you are after examples of swift evolution -There is a nice example of the Waterlily Beetle, *Galerucella nymphaeae* (Fig. 2), that shows striking *host-race formation*, i.e., the same species of beetle shows clear adaptations (on an evolutional scale) dependent on which plant it has been found. It has been shown that these beetles extracted from different plants (*Nymphaeaceae* versus *Polygonaceae*) showed strong **morphological** and **ecological differentiation** to their different host plant families. Beetles from *Nymphaeaceae* were significantly **larger** and had disproportionally **larger mandibles** than beetles from *Polygonaceae*. It is argued that these differences are **adaptations** (on an evolutional scale) to the **tougher leaves** of the *Nymphaeaceae*, which has been linked to **genetic differences**. In addition, females showed a strong **oviposition preference**, and all beetles showed distinct **feeding preferences** for the host family from which they originated. Moreover, these host preferences resulted in clear **differences in survival**: survival was 2 to 11 times higher on the natal host family than on the alternative host family.

[image: Waterlily Beetle]
<sup>Fig. 2. Waterlily Beetle. Source: [Wikipedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Galerucella_nymphaeae_2.jpg).</sup>

Exactly how fast these beetles have adapted I am unsure of, but the interesting thing is that these beetle races are *not geographically separated* by a natural barrier like a sea, a mountain range etc. Instead, they live side-by-side, but have adapted to **a specific host plant**.

<sub>**Reference**

**-** [Pappers, Evolution in action: Host race formation in *Galerucella nymphaeae*. PhD thesis (2001), Radboud University, Nijmegen, the Netherlands](http://repository.ubn.ru.nl/bitstream/handle/2066/19064/19064_evolinac.pdf?sequence=1)</sub>

Comment: Thanks for that answer ! Do you know the name of that snake. Is it Anaconda?